# I don't understand parameter declaration

Tags: c#

I got this assignment which to declare a method like this...

```
public List<Contact> GetLastContacts([int count = 20])  
{  
    return this._entities.ContactsSet.ToList();  
}
```

What I don't understand and can't find info about is `[int count = 20]` as parameter...

Anyone got an explanation on what they mean?

/Best regards!

Comment: Where did you see this? The `[]` are not standard C# around parameters.

Comment: @Oded: "I got this assignment" Something tells me the `[]` is related to the assignment itself but I guess none of us will be able to figure out how.

Comment: @BoltClock - Missed that bit... I concentrated on the code too much ;)

Comment: The `[]` are shown as part of the tooltip when you inspect the method declaration. They should not be written in code. Visual Studio will show any optional parameters inside `[]`

Comment: Thanks for these fast responses. This declaration was written in a documentation and thats what confused me...I never had seen or used it so had to ask here :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int count = 20` in a parameter declares it as a default value for the parameter. It makes the parameter optional for callers (or rather look optional for callers).

So, in a method calling it you can do:

```
var contacts = GetLastContacts(); // Will compile to GetLastContacts(20)
```

Or, to use a value to override the default:

```
var contacts = GetLastContacts(35);
```

See [Named and Optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

`public List<Contact> GetLastContacts(int count = 20)` (no `[]`) means the method has an `int` parameter called `count`, but that the parameter is optional, and if the caller leaves it out and just calls `GetLastContacts()` the default value for `count` is `20`.

The square brackets are incorrect in C# *code*, but they can appear in documentation, tooltips etc. as an indication that the parameter is optional.

Comment: @xbonez - Yes it does. Since version 3.0 - the feature is called Optional Arguments, but defaults is what it is.

Comment: Indeed...I guess it was added somewhere down the line. Withdrawn my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be a combination of two ways to write "optional parameter". In C#, you can define a method with optional arguments if you specify a default argument value with "assignment" like

```
public List<Contact> GetLastContacts(int count = 20)
```

You can then either call

```
GetLastContacts(count)
```

to specify the count, or

```
GetLastContacts()
```

which uses the default value of 20.

The usage of `[ ]` in your code might be POSIX standardized way to write optional parameters, which has no reason to be there at all as it's not supported by C# language nor its documentation standards.